# Select value null after form submission

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have a form in which i toggle '`input text>` with `<select>` using radio buttons. The problem is, i get the result back correctly when user enters value in `<input text>` but not with `<select>`.

Basically i'm sending searchType(the `radio buttons` that selects either the `<input text>` or the `select`) and searchKey(the values of `<input text>` or the `select`). When i use the `<input text>` the values are transferred after form submission whereas no values are transferred using `select` although the name is same for both. i.e searchKey

Can anyone please point out the fault in the code?

```
<div class="well">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/modules/singoliMandrini/ricerca/viewRicerca.jsp" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Ricerca un mandrini</legend>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Search by</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label> <input onclick="showStuff('selection','status');" type="radio" name="searchType" value="id_singoli" />id mandrino</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label> <input onclick="showStuff('selection','status');" type="radio" name="searchType" value="id_tipo" />id tipo</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label> <input onclick="showStuff('selection','status');" type="radio" name="searchType" value="model" />model</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label> <input onclick="showStuff('status','selection');" type="radio" name="searchType" value="status" />stato</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label> <input onclick="showStuff('selection','status');" type="radio" name="searchType" value="linea" />linea</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group tempHide" id="selection">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Search keywords</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchKey" placeholder="keywords" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group tempHide" id="status">
                            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Search keywords</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="searchKey">
                                    <option value="disponibile">disponibile</option>
                                    <option value="montato">montato</option>
                                    <option value="scrap">scrap</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="text-right">
                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Ricerca"   name="ricerca" />
            </p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <% if(request.getParameter("ricerca")!=null) { 
            ricercaTipo ric = new ricercaTipo();
            ArrayList<ricercaBean> list = new ArrayList<ricercaBean>();
            list = ric.search(ricerca);
            if(list.size()>0){
        %>
        <div class="well">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>RPM</th>
                    <th>Nota</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <%  for(int index=0;index<list.size();index++) { %>
                <tr class="active">
                    <td><%=index+1%></td>
                    <td><%=list.get(index).getId_mandrino()%></td>
                    <td><%=list.get(index).getId_tipo()%></td>
                    <td><%=list.get(index).getModel()%></td>
                    <td><%=list.get(index).getTimeStamp()%></td>
                    <td><%=list.get(index).getStatus()%></td>
                </tr>
            <%} %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <% }else{%>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>

        <strong>Oh No!</strong> No data found for the term "<%=ricerca.getSearchType()%>" <%=ricerca.getSearchKey()%>. Try again.
```

I am using Jsp Beans to send the data.

Comment: I don't see with which value it does and with which value it does not work? Could you update the question a little? I think there are some words missing

Comment: edited and updated. hope it makes more sense now. sorry i am not so good at english. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select dropdown and text input both have the same name so their value are mapped to the same variable on the bean. You should give them different names

Comment: Thank you! I have been pulling my hair all day long to solve this one!